# POST/PUT via URL path vs via parameters in JAX-RS Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm implementing a webservice in Java using the RESTful Jersey API.

I got a post request working using 2 distinct ways. You either post something to your server via a URL that includes the values of the fields you want to send in the URL path itself (e.g. http://server.se/Context_root/value1/value2/...) in the correct order defined at the server, and you simply:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());    
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Or you post always to the same URL (e.g. http://server.se/Context_root), and send the fields as parameters like so:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

Where params is something like:

```
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

To which you simply add the name/value pair for each field you want to send:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(field, value));
```

Why are there 2 ways of doing the same thing in the same API? In what cases is one way preferable to the other?

Comment: Don't know about the API, I'm not really more than a Java dabbler occasionally, but this looks like a question of idempotency really: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html or http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/

Comment: I would never ever use the uri templates to pass post parameters. It's about semantics and RESTfulness. I could think of many more ways to post data, other than the two you have above. You could send it as query param, matrix params, headers. But all of these are horrible ideas. If you are posting data, send the data in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the path parameters (http://server.se/Context_root/something) is to add in the context in the something object. For example, for a web service containing a set of cars (dealers with cars in inventory), you will add a car like this:
http://something.com/dealer1/cars. With the PathParam of your rest service, you will have access to the name of the dealer to add cars in it.

Instead, if you add a dealer, you don't need to specify anything (except maybe the city), then you will do http://something.com/dealers to post the new dealer information's.

The REST specification don't recommend to pass values of the objects with the path parameters.

As the wikipedia article says (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), the path is representing resources.